# How to speed up this histogram of LUT lookups?

Tags: c++, optimization, histogram, simd

First, I have an array `int a[1000][1000]`.  All these integers are between 0 and 32767 ,and they are known constants: they never change during a run of the program.

Second, I have an array b[32768], which contains integers between 0 and 32.  I use this array to map all arrays in a to 32 bins:

```
int bins[32]{};
for (auto e : a[i])//mapping a[i] to 32 bins.
    bins[b[e]]++;
```

Each time, array b will be initialized with a new array, and I need to hash all those 1000 arrays in **array a** (each contains 1000 ints) to 1000 arrays each contains 32 ints represents for how many ints fall into its each bin .

```
int new_array[32768] = {some new mapping};
copy(begin(new_array), end(new_array), begin(b));//reload array b;

int bins[1000][32]{};//output array to store results .
for (int i = 0; i < 1000;i++)
    for (auto e : a[i])//hashing a[i] to 32 bins.
        bins[i][b[e]]++;
```

I can map 1000*1000 values in 0.00237 seconds.  Is there any other way that I can speed up my code?  (Like SIMD?)  This piece of code is the bottleneck of my program.

Comment: please post a [MCVE] including demo input data and expected output data

Comment: did you consider CUDA?

Comment: That code is totally memory constrained, so throwing additional compute power at it will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Is there any simple relation between the successive contents of array `b` ? Or any regularity in `b`?

Comment: I would check if your compiler actually optimize `std::copy` to `memcpy`  (as it is a contiguous memory of trivially copiable type), if not, try using `memcpy` instead. also, consider using just one cotiguous array instead

Comment: You have two different declarations of `bins` in the two fragments. The second one has a buffer overflow.

Comment: Related: tiny histograms (like 4 buckets) can use `count[0] += (arr[i] == 0)` which you can vectorize with SIMD packed compares - [Micro Optimization of a 4-bucket histogram of a large array or list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61122144)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially a histogram problem.  You're mapping values 16-bit values to 5-bit values with a 32k-entry lookup table, but after that it's just histogramming the LUT results.  Like `++counts[ b[a[j]] ];`, where `counts` is `bins[i]`. See below for more about histograms.

First of all, you can use the smallest possible data-types to increase the density of your LUT (and of the original data).  On x86, a zero or sign-extending load of 8-bit or 16-bit data into a register is almost exactly the same cost as a regular 32-bit `int` load (assuming both hit in cache), and an 8-bit or 16-bit store is also just as cheap as a 32-bit store.

Since your data size exceeds L1 d-cache size (32kiB for all recent Intel designs), and you access it in a scattered pattern, **you have a lot to gain from shrinking your cache footprint**.  (For more x86 perf info, see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, especially Agner Fog's stuff).

Since `a` has less than 65536 entries in each plane, your bin counts will never overflow a 16-bit counter, so `bins` can be `uint16_t` as well.

---

Your `copy()` makes no sense.  Why are you copying into `b[32768]` instead of having your inner loop use a pointer to the current LUT?  You use it read-only.  The only reason you'd still want to copy is to copy from `int` to `uin8_t` if you can't change the code that produces different LUTs to produce `int8_t` or `uint8_t` in the first place.

This version takes advantage of those ideas and a few histogram tricks, and compiles to asm that looks good ([Godbolt compiler explorer: gcc6.2 `-O3 -march=haswell` (AVX2)](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:%27-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell%27,sourcez:PTDEEsDsGMBsFcAmBTABAHgIawOYHsAncAFwAsBbAPgCgIYEUMBnYxKYgOlJuuj0hap2qAAoAZAIIA5AKIBlVAF5UARgAMGgNzUAbnnCJU8JsgD6AIyhMAFPHYqAbKeKpLAgNrjp8gLruAzABMPgCU2tSokVHRMbGRIKgOAKxJ/g6ohKik4DikyASoxEQ4OPlMhXmoLJjE4NCmmEwmBMTU2DmQjdYOACwhVcQ1dUb2Ti6YnpKycn7qGj6a8cADQ9DAOLB45tgANKgAkqg48MhNAPzUuvqGCMQNkIim2Sx4OASY5LbsABzOqKamAinIp1O6mVC3AKBADsDm%2BoWoAG9LtF2jhOjZHP07JBiI4/m4mJNvDMoQslqhEPwAOQuABe%2BTwFTQAHdSHhYGgyFAcEYAA6oABmBH4xAAXBUaqgWXh4LBDMgdKDUORCGhEDVMEKReRUNBMNBKmRMJBUJBkNBTkxMAQAJ4ROKOp3Op0JABCyGIxHy0tl8tcaAZIp5zNQQM5OhNLj5sBNaDwgtQyANpFcUDDOVILnMyEFaqMTB5HAdLtLZdiCVtstQfMwttDQIFLyYAEcVi14AK8Dp8nlMIZVUDCuByKc9mRZbliyWhZlrMJwEpUGpFov0KIpvJNOAANQ7/rIx1ojHWLEjXH4lzEch8wnuHp%2BII%2BJeItQAX20jr4Am9AA8%2BQUwiYKYyCcuQ5TKIWDIJtYExqKEwBQcgME4niYxhDO0TVLU9SNM0xCwSBYHlJQqh7AAREweCjvwaCGiapSGBMz7sEymAAFSoCahh5gQ%2BBXkynYat6FTgOUfAoORGGOthdQNE0%2BQEcBoHIOBGDKAAqvsUgACr4gAshIAAaFGEnqfqGN2%2BSCpsLJSZ%2BcTfoIqGXqg7GYIuygTOACyYVEvGoPOuKoAAVkuaioIsIVYERqnlFFO6KH0qCIqgICkI02SQLy3nPsQTJBGmAjFqWCQaZAIqwLAIb5VUyC1u8IluFxBDvLa5RAog8CWuUzTgNglL1cgDzDdA4CnH5FbLLVmB6AYrh4F6nLmtAADW5RssNobWqORVCOUxjIIYjbJt6iCwLaJUugkOnPFkjSFEyOauNgJqWkxOAeT%2BBY1XgTLkN1qZiCoeopmgAVkGghJXc6163lY7jwe4ELwMQ7gee4IU7vBz4%2BHuDmwzed4qH4KNoxjWMk7j%2BOTTEcN3sEyOQhTO7BNTO4E069MI/4pPM%2BAmM7rz7OczJgw4fJ%2BGESpakAKSoD0SjKGoFHwBVHKwEKBr5QUVKnJAtKUuASqMFqMvDS4fBq8Q9m02%2BtMBUFLireFkWoKt6CFYsq17getPRAkODQNAlJ4KcXGo3gAC0PbQDr4AMqJG0kKmWpMOyLRCnKF1R2rlWcoYABq%2BkAPKFwAIgAihIaWoIXIgSOX5cAOqoL%2B/j%2B1Ed4%2Be4q3Pso3MeEjfeoDuhREwjJO98%2BO6d%2BW4/wx4jMj2Pg9Erz0%2Bi1E9vRDvqAzgkVJVNRnpZbyLIp0VTAcJEEimsgv7egQpqCmrcfgPwAx4Hy5QkNq1EZD5LUcgCcQyYBZHWGGBYzCEmsISDCb4gA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)):

```
// untested
//#include <algorithm>
#include <stdint.h>

const int PLANES = 1000;
void use_bins(uint16_t bins[PLANES][32]);   // pass the result to an extern function so it doesn't optimize away

                       // 65536 or higher triggers the static_assert
alignas(64) static uint16_t a[PLANES][1000];  // static/global, I guess?

void lut_and_histogram(uint8_t __restrict__ lut[32768])
{

    alignas(16) uint16_t bins[PLANES][32];  // don't zero the whole thing up front: that would evict more data from cache than necessary
                                            // Better would be zeroing the relevant plane of each bin right before using.
                                            // you pay the rep stosq startup overhead more times, though.

    for (int i = 0; i < PLANES;i++) {
        alignas(16) uint16_t tmpbins[4][32] = {0};
        constexpr int a_elems = sizeof(a[0])/sizeof(uint16_t);
        static_assert(a_elems > 1, "someone changed a[] into a* and forgot to update this code");
        static_assert(a_elems <= UINT16_MAX, "bins could overflow");
        const uint16_t *ai = a[i];
        for (int j = 0 ; j<a_elems ; j+=4) { //hashing a[i] to 32 bins.
            // Unrolling to separate bin arrays reduces serial dependencies
            // to avoid bottlenecks when the same bin is used repeatedly.
            // This has to be balanced against using too much L1 cache for the bins.

            // TODO: load a vector of data from ai[j] and unpack it with pextrw.
            // even just loading a uint64_t and unpacking it to 4 uint16_t would help.
            tmpbins[0][ lut[ai[j+0]] ]++;
            tmpbins[1][ lut[ai[j+1]] ]++;
            tmpbins[2][ lut[ai[j+2]] ]++;
            tmpbins[3][ lut[ai[j+3]] ]++;
            static_assert(a_elems % 4 == 0, "unroll factor doesn't divide a element count");
        }

        // TODO: do multiple a[i] in parallel instead of slicing up a single run.
        for (int k = 0 ; k<32 ; k++) {
            // gcc does auto-vectorize this with a short fully-unrolled VMOVDQA / VPADDW x3
            bins[i][k] = tmpbins[0][k] + tmpbins[1][k] +
                         tmpbins[2][k] + tmpbins[3][k];
        }
    }
  
    // do something with bins.  An extern function stops it from optimizing away.
    use_bins(bins);
}
```

The inner-loop asm looks like this:

```
.L2:
    movzx   ecx, WORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rdx, 8                    # pointer increment over ai[]
    movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rsi+rcx]
    add     WORD PTR [rbp-64272+rcx*2], 1     # memory-destination increment of a histogram element
    movzx   ecx, WORD PTR [rdx-6]
    movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rsi+rcx]
    add     WORD PTR [rbp-64208+rcx*2], 1
    ... repeated twice more
```

With those 32-bit offsets from rbp (instead of 8-bit offsets from rsp, or using another register :/) the code density isn't wonderful.  Still, the average instruction length isn't so long that it's likely to bottleneck on instruction decode on any modern CPU.

---

#### A variation on multiple bins:

Since you need to do multiple histograms anyway, just do 4 to 8 of them in parallel instead of slicing the bins for a single histogram.  The unroll factor doesn't even have to be a power of 2.

That eliminates the need for the `bins[i][k] = sum(tmpbins[0..3][k])` loop over `k` at the end.

Zero `bins[i..i+unroll_factor][0..31]` right before use, instead of zeroing the whole thing outside the loop.  That way all the bins will be hot in L1 cache when you start, and this work can overlap with the more load-heavy work of the inner loop.

Hardware prefetchers can keep track of multiple sequential streams, so don't worry about having a lot more cache misses in loading from `a`.  (Also use vector loads for this, and slice them up after loading).

---

Other questions with useful answers about histograms:

- [Methods to vectorise histogram in SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985949/methods-to-vectorise-histogram-in-simd) suggests the multiple-bin-arrays and sum at the end trick.
- [Optimizing SIMD histogram calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970060/optimizing-simd-histogram-calculation) x86 asm loading a vector of `a` values and extracting to integer registers with pextrb.  (In your code, you'd use [`pextrw` / `_mm_extract_epi16`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXTRW.html)).  **With all the load/store uops happening, doing a vector load and using ALU ops to unpack  makes sense**.  With good L1 hit rates, memory uop throughput may be the bottleneck, not memory / cache latency.
- [How to optimize histogram statistics with neon intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501529/how-to-optimize-histogram-statistics-with-neon-intrinsics) some of the same ideas: multiple copies of the bins array.  It also has an ARM-specific suggestion for doing address calculations in a SIMD vector (ARM can get two scalars from a vector in a single instruction), and laying out the multiple-bins array the opposite way.

---

#### AVX2 Gather instructions for the LUT

If you're going to run this on Intel Skylake, you could maybe even do the LUT lookups with AVX2 gather instructions.  (On Broadwell, it's probably a break-even, and on Haswell it would lose; they support [`vpgatherdd` (`_mm_i32gather_epi32`)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPGATHERDD:VPGATHERQD.html), but don't have as efficient an implementation.  Hopefully Skylake avoids hitting the same cache line multiple times when there is overlap between elements).

And yes, you can still gather from an array of `uint16_t` (with scale factor = 2), even though the smallest gather granularity is 32-bit elements.  It means you get garbage in the high half of each 32-bit vector element instead of 0, but that shouldn't matter.  Cache-line splits aren't ideal, since we're probably bottlenecked on cache throughput.

Garbage in the high half of gathered elements doesn't matter because you're extracting only the useful 16 bits anyway with `pextrw`.  (And doing the histogram part of the process with scalar code).

You *could* potentially use another gather to load from the histogram bins, as long as each element comes from a separate slice/plane of histogram bins.  Otherwise, if two elements come from the same bin, it would only be incremented by one when you manually scatter the incremented vector back into the histogram (with scalar stores).  This kind of conflict detection for scatter stores is why [AVX512CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_conflict_detection) exists.  AVX512 does have scatter instructions, as well as gather (already added in AVX2).

---

**AVX512**

See [page 50 of Kirill Yukhin's slides from 2014](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cauldron2014?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Cauldron14_AVX-512_Vector_ISA_Kirill_Yukhin_20140711.pdf#page=50) for an example loop that retries until there are no conflicts; but it doesn't show how `get_conflict_free_subset()` is implemented in terms of `__m512i _mm512_conflict_epi32 (__m512i a)` (`vpconflictd`) (which returns a bitmap in each element of all the preceding elements it conflicts with).  As @Mysticial points out, a simple implementation is less simple than it would be if the conflict-detect instruction simply produced a mask-register result, instead of another vector.

I searched for but didn't find an Intel-published tutorial/guide on using AVX512CD, but presumably they think using `_mm512_lzcnt_epi32` (`vplzcntd`) on the result of `vpconflictd` is useful for some cases, because it's also part of AVX512CD.

Maybe you're "supposed" to do something more clever than just skipping all elements that have any conflicts?  Maybe to detect a case where a scalar fallback would be better, e.g. all 16 dword elements have the same index?  `vpbroadcastmw2d` broadcasts a mask register to all 32-bit elements of the result, so that lets you line up a mask-register value with the bitmaps in each element from `vpconflictd`.  (And there are already compare, bitwise, and other operations between elements from AVX512F).

Kirill's slides list `VPTESTNM{D,Q}` (from AVX512F) along with the conflict-detection instructions.  It generates a mask from `DEST[j] = (SRC1[i+31:i] BITWISE AND SRC2[i+31:i] == 0)? 1 : 0`.  i.e. AND elements together, and set the mask result for that element to 1 if they don't intersect.

---

Possibly also relevant: http://colfaxresearch.com/knl-avx512/ says ["For a practical illustration, we construct and optimize a micro-kernel for particle binning particles"](http://colfaxresearch.com/optimization-techniques-for-the-intel-mic-architecture-part-2-of-3-strip-mining-for-vectorization/), with some code for AVX2 (I think).  But it's behind a free registration which I haven't done.  Based on the diagram, I think they're doing the actual scatter part as scalar, after some vectorized stuff to produce data they want to scatter.  The first link says the 2nd link is "for previous instruction sets".

---

### Avoid gather/scatter conflict detection by replicating the count array

When the number of buckets is small compared to the size of the array, it becomes viable to replicate the count arrays and unroll to minimize store-forwarding latency bottlenecks with repeated elements.   But for a gather/scatter strategy, it also avoids the possibility of conflicts, solving the correctness problem, if we use a different array for each vector element.

How can we do that when a gather / scatter instruction only takes one array base?  Make all the count arrays contiguous, and offset each *index* vector with one extra SIMD add instruction, fully replacing conflict detection and branching.

If the number of buckets isn't a multiple of 16, you might want to round up the array geometry so each subset of counts starts at an aligned offset.  Or not, if cache locality is more important than avoiding unaligned loads in the reduction at the end.

```
    const size_t nb = 32;  // number of buckets
    const int VEC_WIDTH = 16;  // sizeof(__m512i) / sizeof(uint32_t)
    alignas(__m512i) uint32_t counts[nb * VEC_WIDTH] = {0};

// then in your histo loop

    __m512i idx = ...;  // in this case from LUT lookups
    idx = _mm512_add_epi32(idx, _mm512_setr_epi32(
       0*nb, 1*nb,  2*nb,  3*nb,   4*nb,  5*nb,  6*nb,  7*nb,
       8*nb, 9*nb, 10*nb, 11*nb,  12*nb, 13*nb, 14*nb, 15*nb));
       // note these are C array indexes, not byte offsets
    __m512i vc = _mm512_i32gather_epi32(idx, counts, sizeof(counts[0]));
    vc = _mm512_add_epi32(vc, _mm512_set1_epi32(1));
    _mm512_i32scatter_epi32(counts, idx, vc, sizeof(counts[0]));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8Kesx7sEK shows that the above code actually compiles.  (Inside a loop, the vector-constant setup could get hoisted, but not setting mask registers to all-one before each gather or scatter, or preparing a zeroed merge destination.)

Then after the main histogram loop, reduce down to one count array:

```
// Optionally with size_t nb as an arg
// also optionally use restrict if you never reduce in-place, into the bottom of the input.
void reduce_counts(int *output, const int *counts)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nb - (VEC_WIDTH-1) ; i+=VEC_WIDTH) {
        __m512i v = _mm512_load_si512(&counts[i]);  // aligned load, full cache line
        // optional: unroll this and accumulate two vectors in parallel for better spatial locality and more ILP
        for (int offset = nb; offset < nb*VEC_WIDTH ; offset+=nb) {
            __m512i tmp = _mm512_loadu_si512(&counts[i + offset]);
            v = _mm512_add_epi32(v, tmp);
        }
        _mm512_storeu_si512(&output[i], v);
    }

   // if  nb isn't a multiple of the vector width, do some cleanup here
   // possibly using a masked store to write into a final odd-sized destination
}
```

Obviously this is bad with too many buckets; you end up having to zero way more memory, and loop over a lot of it at the end.  Using 256-bit instead of 512-bit gathers helps, you only need half as many arrays, but efficiency of gather/scatter instructions improves with wider vectors.  e.g. one `vpgatherdd` per 5 cycles for 256-bit on Cascade Lake, one per 9.25 for 512-bit.  (And both are 4 uops for the front-end)

Or on Ice Lake, one `vpscatterdd` ymm per 7 cycles, one zmm per 11 cycles.  (vs. 14 for 2x ymm).  https://uops.info/

In your `bins[1000][32]` case, you could actually use the later elements of `bins[i+0..15]` as extra count arrays, if you zero first, at least for the first 1000-15 outer loop iterations.  That would avoid touching extra memory: zeroing for the next outer loop would start at the previous `counts[32]`, effectively.

(This would be playing a bit fast and loose with C 2D vs. 1D arrays, but all the actual accesses past the end of the `[32]` C array type would be via `memset` (i.e. `unsigned char*`) or via `_mm*` intrinsics which are also allowed to alias anything)

---

Related:

- Tiny histograms (like 4 buckets) can use `count[0] += (arr[i] == 0)` and so on, which you can vectorize with SIMD packed compares - [Micro Optimization of a 4-bucket histogram of a large array or list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61122144)  This is interesting when the number of buckets is less than or equal to the number of elements in a SIMD vector.

Comment: I've come to the point where I can recognize that an answer is yours from just the first paragraph. That scares me.

Comment: @Mysticial: I consider that a compliment.  I never wanted to be a normal person like everyone/anyone else. :)

Comment: I've been looking at the conflict-detection intrinsics. do you have any idea why they return 0/1 instead of a mask? The only reasonable implementation for histogramming that I can come up with is to take the output of `vpconflict`, turn it into a mask, then do the masked gather-increment-scatter. The vector compares can return masks and are masked themselves. So it can't be an issue of not having the right instruction class to do it. Perhaps the instruction class for vector compares somehow can't do cross-lane data-dependencies as required by `vpconflict`.

Comment: @Mysticial: It's not just a 0/1 per element; it's a bitmap (as I realized after squinting at the pseudocode long enough).  There's more information than you could put into a mask, but I'm not sure what you're "supposed" to do with it.  It does seem like in many cases, you'd just want to turn it into a mask based on zero/non-zero and just do all the non-conflicting elements.  Updated my answer with some rambling about how IDK what it's for either, and that I wish Intel would publish a tutorial on how they intended the insns to be used.

Comment: Oh you're right. The pseudo-code deceived me. Looks like it also tells you *what* it conflicted with. I guess it's not as cryptic as the multi-shift instructions in VBMI which I have no f**'ing clue what they're supposed to do or what their intended use-case is.

Comment: @Mysticial: Wow, that's an impressively complex insn.  (There's only one `VPMULTISHIFTQB`, BTW, no other combos of granularity.)  The PDF version (Intel's future-extensions update to the asm insn ref manual) has more verbose English text describing the operation.  And the Operation section has comments in the pseudocode (but is more complex because it handles the broadcast-or-not cases, and zero/merge/no-masking (at byte granularity), but still overall I think is clearer.)  I'm not sure I've grokked it, but I think it'd be good for converting between 10bit packed YUV and 16bit padded.

Comment: At the end of Yukhin's slide 50 he writes "This not even the fastest version: see backup for details"...Do you have any idea where this backup is?

Comment: In Intel's optimization manual they implement filling a histogram using the conflict instructions (Example 16-4). Actually, they show the disassembly from a compiler they claim vectorized it. I have not succeeded in getting ICC 17 to vectorize it. Maybe GCC will do it but I don't have a recent version of GCC installed on my KNL system. Anyway, it might interest you. I have got it partly working with intrinsics.