# How to Shuffle a Vector128<T> and Add the elements, then Extract a scalar value properly?

Tags: c#, sse, simd, intrinsics, sse2

I am using `Vector128<byte>` in **C#** in order to count matches from a byte array with 16 index.

This is part of implementing a byte version of [Micro Optimization of a 4-bucket histogram of a large array or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122144/micro-optimization-of-a-4-bucket-histogram-of-a-large-array-or-list), using the technique from [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541129/how-to-count-character-occurrences-using-simd) of widening 8-bit counters to 64 inside an outer loop (`hsum_epu8_epu64` helper function), and then after all the loops of summing that vector of counters down to one scalar (`hsum_epu64_scalar`).

So that C++ with Intel intrinsics has to be ported to C#.  And without AVX2 so we're using 128-bit integer vectors, not 256.

---

The byte array consists of numbers `0` and `1` where 5 `0` occurs.

The task now is to count those 5 `0` where we can see that 2 of the `0` occurs in the upperband of the `Vector128<byte>` and 3 of the `0` occurs in the lowerband of the `Vector128<byte>`.

I have succeed with code all the way to where I `Sse2.SumAbsoluteDifferences` and can extract the number of `0` for `sumHigh` and `sumLow` showing 3 and 2 respectively.

The problem starts now where I need to shuffle so the upperband and lowerband change places so I later can extract the opposites in: `sumHigh` and `sumLow` for `sum64b`

I have put a lot of comments in the code also so I think it is possible to follow the code and see there also exactly how I try to shuffle and complete the code.

*(The code shows also that my AMD K10 processor supports: Sse, Sse2, Sse3)*

```
    using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
    using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This shows what is supported on my processor. However it seems that I could use something from "Avx" anyway
        bool avx = Avx.IsSupported; //false
        bool avx2 = Avx2.IsSupported; //false

        bool sse = Sse.IsSupported; //true
        bool sse2 = Sse2.IsSupported; //true
        bool sse3 = Sse3.IsSupported; //true
        bool ssse3 = Ssse3.IsSupported; //false
        bool sse41 = Sse41.IsSupported; //false
        bool sse42 = Sse42.IsSupported; //false

        //Create a bytearray of 16 indexes. As seen: '0' occur 2 times in the upper band and 3 times in the lower band
        //We want to count those "0" in the below code
        byte[] v1 = new byte[16];
        v1[0] = 0; v1[1] = 0; v1[2] = 1; v1[3] = 1; v1[4] = 1; v1[5] = 1; v1[6] = 1; v1[7] = 1;
        v1[8] = 1; v1[9] = 0; v1[10] = 0; v1[11] = 0; v1[12] = 1; v1[13] = 1; v1[14] = 1; v1[15] = 1;

        Vector128<byte> counts = Vector128<byte>.Zero;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* fixedInput = v1)
            {
                //Load byte Vector with 16 indexes
                var v = Avx.LoadVector128(&fixedInput[0]);

                //Now match how many "0" we can find in "Vector128: v". 'counts' show the result string where: '1' tells where we found: "0".
                //As seen it happened as expected total times: 5 (2 times in the upper band and 3 times in the lower band of the Vector)
                byte val = 0;
                var match = Avx.CompareEqual(v, Vector128.Create(val));
                counts = Avx.Subtract(counts, match); //counts: <1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0>



                //Extract high/low bands
                //So we use "SumAbsoluteDifferences" to "Separately sum the 8 low differences and 8 high differences to produce two unsigned word integer results."
                //We can see on index 0: 2 and on index 4: 3
                Vector128<ushort> sum64 = Vector128<ushort>.Zero;
                sum64 = Sse2.Add(sum64, Sse2.SumAbsoluteDifferences(counts, Vector128<byte>.Zero)); //sum64: <2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0>

                //I AM NOT SURE OF THE CODE BELOW HOW TO DO IT PROPERLY!

                //Now I need to shuffle the above: "<2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0>" but are not sure of how the complete process is to do this correctly?
                //Below is a start of an "attempt" but are not sure how to do this all the way correctly?

                Vector128<uint> result = Sse2.Shuffle(sum64.AsUInt32(), 0xB1); 

                //Extract high/low bands from ther shuffle above?
                //Vector128<uint> sum64b = Vector128<uint>.Zero;
                //sum64b = Sse2.Add(sum64b, result);
                //sumHigh = Sse2.Extract(sum64b, 1); //0
                //sumLow = Sse2.Extract(sum64b, 0); //                                                                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Using 16-bit extracts would be possible but not usable for larger counts.

```
    var sumHigh = Sse2.Extract(sum64, 4);    // pextrw
    var sumLow = Sse2.Extract(sum64, 0); //sumHigh == 3 and sumLow == 2
    var sumScalar = SumLow + sumHigh;
```

---

Note from @PeterCordes: the real use-case would loop to add up to 255 vectors into `counts`, then in an outer loop accumulate into wide elements in `sum64` with `Sse2.SumAbsoluteDifferences` and `Sse2.Add`, and reset `counts`.  That part looks correct in this C# port, except that `sum64` should not use `ushort` elements.

**The part this question is asking about is the horizontal sum of two 64-bit vector elements down to one scalar integer.**  (The real use-case has three vectors of counts, from 3 histogram buckets;  a transpose and sum could work but simply doing separate horizontal sums for each vector is fine.)

Comment: `sum64` should be a `Vector128<uint>` or `Vector128<Uint64>`.  Using `Sse2.Extract(sum64, 4);` (`pextrw`) to extra a 16-bit chunk is not going to work for your real use-case because counts can be larger than 65535.

Comment: `Vector128<uint> srcAsUInt32 = counts.AsUInt32();` - this should be `sum64.AsUInt32();`  You were taking the 8-bit count buckets, not the `psadbw` result.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks again for the help with the question! Yes you are right that is what I can see also. The problem where I get stuck is that `Sse2.Extract(` only can return an `ushort` and the that function can also only accept `Vector128<ushort>` as a parameter. I am not sure but it seems that I get stuck there because I like to use `<uint>` for example so no overflow can occur. From the code: `Sse2.Shuffle(` down to `Sse2.Extract(` I can't even find a combination of types that will work because they accept different types.

Comment: `sum64.AsUInt32();` Yes ofcourse that is true. That must be the one to pass there. I did a mistake there also.

Comment: You might want to fix that bug in your question since it distracts from what you're asking about.  But anyway, so apparently don't use `Extract`.  Use a vector to vector shuffle and Add.  Then surely there's some way to get the low element other than `Extract`?  In C++ there are special intrinsics for getting the low element as a scalar, other than extract.  Otherwise at worst you could transpose and add two `sum64` vectors (from two buckets) with unpacklo/unpackhi (`punpcklqdq`) for a vector store into an array of `Uint64`.  Or even worse just store into a tmp array and reload as scalar.

Comment: Yes perheps this actually worked. Lets see what you think. I am stuck with that `Sse2.SumAbsoluteDifferences` must return a `ushort` so `sum64` is  a `ushort`. But then I used the `Unpack` like this and in the messageBox I could convert to Scalar and get the numbers `3` and `2`: .... `Vector128<ushort> upper = Sse2.UnpackHigh(sum64, sum64); Vector128<ushort> lower = Sse2.UnpackLow(sum64, sum64); MessageBox.Show(upper.ToScalar() + ":" + lower.ToScalar());` Could this be  a valid solution. Then I will pass `3` and `2` to `Int64` counters to not overflow and then reset after each `255` iteration?

Comment: Yes, UnpackHigh looks useful, but you definitely want to use it on a `Vector128<Uint64>`, not to interleave 16-bit `ushort` elements.  And you can do a SIMD Sse2.Add instead of 2 separate `ToScalar()`.  But yes, `.ToScalar()` is presumably the intrinsic for `movd / movq`, so yes that's the right building block to use instead of `.Extract` (`pextrw`).

Comment: Also, `Sse2.UnpackLow(sum64, sum64)` is pointless.  The low element is already at the bottom, where you want it.  And a `ushort` unpack is just going to produce `(2<<16) | 2` in the low 32 bits when it interleaves the `ushort` elements from the low halves of the two vectors.  To get the right shuffle, you have to use the right method on the right element-type vector with C#, unlike C++ where everything is `__m128i` and the shuffle element size is part of the intrinsic name.

Comment: I did cast the `SumAbsoluteDifferences` function to `.AsUInt64()` so I can go all the way down with that instead and change all types to `UInt64`

Comment: I am not sure why `Sse2.UnpackLow(sum64, sum64)` is pointless. The only thing I can understand there is that I use that method to 
get the value from the lower band? (I am not sure if the scenario changed when using only `UInt64` now)

Comment: Look at the example diagram in the asm manual for [`punpcklbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/punpcklbw:punpcklwd:punpckldq:punpcklqdq) - note that the low element stays the low element.  For 64-bit elements, you're just duplicating the low element to the upper element when you unpack against itself, but you never read that high SIMD element.  https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/ also has some diagrams and categorization of instructions by what they do.

Comment: *so I can go all the way down with that instead and change all types to UInt64* - yes, after SAD, you should treat that vector as having Uint64 elements from that point onwards.  Messing around with 16-bit chunks of those 64-bit numbers is the mistake you need to avoid.

Comment: Yes I looked at the `unpack` in the link there and the "red"/low element color stays at the low from the beginning. But I am not sure how to return the lower value without using: `Sse2.UnpackLow`. Should I use any other syntax on `sum64` to return this value? I think I miss something here how to do that. Perheps I should only use: `sum64.ToScalar()` as it return `2` actually which is the lower element?

Comment: That is great. So I will always think of using `Uint64` so I don't mix around with different types.

Comment: Yes, `vec.ToScalar()` returns the low element of the vector. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128.toscalar?view=netcore-3.1 For a Uint64 vector that's the low 64 bits.  IDK why you thought UnpackLow would be necessary for ToScalar to be usable or to get the desired value, but it's not.

Comment: Yes that did return the lower element. I was not sure it actually did that but could see that in the comment on the syntax itself also. Now I know that also. That is great.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an answer of how to count how many `0` in the upper and lower elements of the `v1` byte array.

Answer will be:
**lower elements: 2

higher elements: 3**

1. So first `Sse2.SumAbsoluteDifferences` is used to:
   *Sum the 8 low differences and 8 high differences to produce two unsigned word integer results*
2. Then we can `Sse2.UnpackHigh` the upper elements
3. Use `sum64.ToScalar()` to get the lower elements because `scalar` cointains the value of the first element.

   ```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Create a bytearray of 16 indexes. As seen: '0' occur 2 times in the upper band and 3 times in the lower band
       //We want to count those "0" in the below code
       byte[] v1 = new byte[16];
       v1[0] = 0; v1[1] = 0; v1[2] = 1; v1[3] = 1; v1[4] = 1; v1[5] = 1; v1[6] = 1; v1[7] = 1;
       v1[8] = 1; v1[9] = 0; v1[10] = 0; v1[11] = 0; v1[12] = 1; v1[13] = 1; v1[14] = 1; v1[15] = 1;

       Vector128<byte> counts = Vector128<byte>.Zero;
       unsafe
       {
           fixed (byte* fixedInput = v1)
           {
               //Load byte Vector with 16 indexes
               var v = Avx.LoadVector128(&fixedInput[0]);

               //Now match how many "0" we can find in "Vector128: v". 'counts' show the result string where: '1' tells where we found: "0".
               //As seen it happened as expected total times: 5 (2 times in the upper band and 3 times in the lower band of the Vector)
               byte val = 0;
               var match = Avx.CompareEqual(v, Vector128.Create(val));
               counts = Avx.Subtract(counts, match); //counts: <1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0>

               //SumAbsoluteDifferences
               Vector128<UInt64> sum64 = Vector128<UInt64>.Zero;
               sum64 = Sse2.Add(sum64, Sse2.SumAbsoluteDifferences(counts, Vector128<byte>.Zero).AsUInt64()); //sum64: <2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0>

               //UnpackHigh and add the lower,upper element from the Vector128<UInt64>
               //var lower = sum64; // low element already where we want it
               UInt64 upper = Sse2.UnpackHigh(sum64, sum64).ToScalar(); //3
               Uint64 total_matches_of_0 = Sse2.Add(sum64, upper).ToScalar(); //2 + 3
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You don't actually want separate upper and lower results, you just want their sum.  So you could do that before ToScalar, like `Uint64 total_matches_of_0 = Sse2.Add(sum64, upper).ToScalar();` to get `5`.  Like `hsum_epu64_scalar` does with a SIMD add before one final `_mm_cvtsi128_si64` (aka ToScalar).

Comment: That was even better. I changed to that line as you mentioned there. Perheps it can still show in the code where the lower comes from just for demonstrating purposes. Now I think I can start experimenting with this code and see how I can create the 2 outer loops and go back to the other thread with the incomplete question later. It was great sorting this problem out. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, `var lower = sum64;  // low element already where we want it`

Comment: Yes it is possible to write it like that. Nice. I changed to that line in the code above also. Thanks again! I will start experimenting a little to see what I can do :)

Comment: /facepalm.  That only makes sense as an input to `Sse2.Add(lower, upper).ToScalar();`  But you left out `Sse2.Add` so now this answer produces a scalar Uint64 from the high half, and a `Vector<Uint64> lower`.

Comment: That was true, I first thought is was a simplifier but yes that was `=` same ofcourse.

Comment: Ok, now your answer is back to not bothering to produce the total answer, just two partial results.  Using  `Sse2.Add()` is more efficient than two `.ToScalar()`.  Of course that's mostly irrelevant for this cleanup after the outer loop, but if you're thinking in SIMD terms then it's the natural way to do the final step.

Comment: Yes lets add that line after all. I just left out the other one to clearly see where the low value comes from but this is better as a complete approach then.

Comment: Like I said, `var lower = sum64; // low element already where we want it` could clearly document that before `Sse2.Add(lower, upper).ToScalar();`

Comment: Yes I added that as a comment before `Sse2.Add(` so this will not actually be declared since it will be an unnecessary extra line then.